# How to create a patch ignoring indentation differences in the code?

Tags: linux, diff, patch

I'm trying to create patch a file using diff tool.But facing an issues.The way I am doing is below.

I've created one Directory named a and put original file in to it.

```
a/original_file.c
```

Now I have created other Directory named b and put same file with modified content  in to it.

```
b/original_file.c
```

Now content of `b/original_file.c` file I have copied from internet and put it into some text editor.

After giving command: `diff -Naur  a b > patch_file.patch`, the file `patch_file.patch` is generated and it has some unwanted changes (its related to indentation).

For example:

```
return mg_nw (MG_READY_NOY, &rmsg, seqnr,
-                 sizeof (struct mg_rdy_notify));
+                  sizeof (struct mg_rdy_notify));
```

Now you can see there are changed related to indentation where `sizeof (struct mg_rdy_notify))` is replaced by same `sizeof (struct mg_rdy_notify))` but one basis of indentation which is what we don't want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`diff` has more than one option related to whitespace.  However, one is less useful for patches.  The manual page gives an obscure hint, referring to both [GNU](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html):

```
   -B, --ignore-blank-lines
          ignore changes where lines are all blank
   -b, --ignore-space-change
          ignore changes in the amount of white space
   -w, --ignore-all-space
          ignore all white space
```

and [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=diff&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Red%20Hat%20Linux%2Fi386%209&format=html)

```
   -b     Ignore changes in amount of white space.
   -B     Ignore changes that just insert or delete blank lines.
   -w     Ignore white space when comparing lines.
```

Usually one uses `-b`, because that is less likely to overlook significant changes.  If you have changed only indentation, then both `-b` and `-w` give the same result.  On the other hand, if you inserted spaces where there were none, or deleted existing spaces (leaving none), that could be a change in your program.  Here is an example:

```
$ diff foo.c foo2.c
4c4
<     setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
---
>     setlocale(LC_ALL, " ");
6,7c6,7
<     printw("\U0001F0A1");
<     getch();
---
>     printw ("\U0001F0A1");
>     getch();  /* comment */
$ diff -b foo.c foo2.c
4c4
<     setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
---
>     setlocale(LC_ALL, " ");
6,7c6,7
<     printw("\U0001F0A1");
<     getch();
---
>     printw ("\U0001F0A1");
>     getch();  /* comment */
$ diff -w foo.c foo2.c
7c7
<     getch();
---
>     getch();  /* comment */
```

In this case, the `-w` option allows you to ignore the change to the `setlocale` parameter (perhaps not what was intended).

[POSIX diff](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html), by the way, has only the `-b` option.

For `patch`, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/patch.html) documents the `-l` option:

> **`-l`**
>       (The letter *ell*.) Cause any sequence of `<blank>` characters in the difference script to match any sequence of `<blank>` characters in the input file. Other characters shall be matched exactly.

Comment: I was astonished this had fewer upvotes until I noticed the timestamps.  Thanks for taking the time; this was very helpful.  :)

Comment: no problem - I've been working through the backlog of questions which I find interesting...

Answer (score 8):

`diff` has an option to ignore whitespace changes (`-w`), same for `patch` (`-l`). In general, it's a bad idea to ignore whitespace though, so you should reserve its use for special cases, when someone's editor did something horrible...

Comment: Thanks @frontschutz ,So my commade would be now diff -Naur -w a b??